# Jquery linked slider display values

Tags: javascript, jquery, uislider

I am using a jquery slider that automatically adjusts so the two sliders only ever show 100%.

All works well I just need to display the two numbers, is this possible?

The code I have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('div.basicLinked').slider().linkedSliders();
        $('div.basicLinked:first').slider('value', 50);
    });
</script>
```

This is then displayed using:

```
<div class="basicLinked"></div>
<div class="basicLinked"></div>
```

Comment: `I just need to display the two numbers`...what two numbers?

Comment: The slider goes up to 100, I need to show the split - so the default would be 50 - 50

Comment: which jQuery slider are you using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess:

```
$('div.basicLinked:first').slider('value')
$('div.basicLinked:last').slider('value')
```

Is that what you need?

Try to explain your problem better.